# Cell EMF in parallel

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

My TB gives the following formula of emf of cells in parallel:

$$\frac V{R_{eq}} = \frac{V_1}{R_1} + \frac{V_2}{R_2}+\frac{V_3}{R_3}+...$$

where

$\frac 1{R_{eq}} = \frac 1{R_1} + \frac 1{R_2}+\frac 1{R_3}+...$

$R_1, R_2, R_3, ...$ are the internal resistances

$V_1, V_2, V_3, ...$ are the individual emfs

How can this be proven? How can the equivalent resistance be calculated when the voltages across the resistors are different?

Comment: You say that everything is connected in a parallel way? Then perhaps $V=V_i,\ i=1,2,3,...$ and then the proof is easy: just multiply your equation $\frac{1}{R_{eff}}=\frac{1}{R_{1}}+\frac{1}{R_{2}}+...$ with $V$

Comment: This is known as Millman's theorem. Yes, you would normally arrive at this result using Kirchhoff's laws. There is another simple way to show it if you know Norton's theorem: replace each branch by its Norton equivalent and combine the current sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Kirchhoff's laws are valid here and also valid for any circuit in general.

The proof for this is quite simple and elegant
[image: Circuit Diagram]

For n cell with individual internal resistances(represented in figure II) , we can assume an equivalent cell (represented in figure I)

We then equate the individual currents in each cell branch to the net current in the equivalent circuit using Kirchhoff's junction rule

We then apply Kirchhoff's voltage rule for each individual branch runing across the whole circuit, obtaining the individual current expressions

We then put in the current expressions in the junction rule expression and Voila! Done.